# Poorly Painted Rebus (4)

Tags: rebus

[image]

What do I think about this picture? It's...

<sub>The answer to this riddle is a common object, being, phrase, or idiom</sub>

Comment: (I'll be honest, a lot of these rebuses seem pretty low quality because of how little went into making them -- not just graphically, but there's not much of a puzzle here either.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rebus represents

> "It's all Greek to me". (That word is "all" in Greek.)

Comment: Dang, sniped! Well played

Answer (score 2):

I think it’s

> It’s all Greek to me!